# What is the origin of the "divine name" of דיקרנוסא

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, language, divine-names

I noticed this kabbalistic holy name "דיקרנוסא" mentioned in the Amidah of a Edot haMizrach siddur in the extra supplications, and apparently it is not allowed to be pronounced. It sounds like it is Latin or Spanish in origin, maybe I'm mistaken. What is the meaning/origin of דיקרנוסא?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing it in Ashkenazi Machzorim (either during Tekiyas Shofar or Birkas Kohanim...somewhere in there)

Comment: @robev The Ashkenazi Artscroll Rosh HaShanah machzor has it in a kabbalistic prayer some recite after Le-David Mizmor (at the end of maariv)

Answer (score 3):

It is customary to recite Tefillat HaParnasah, a prayer for sustenance, at the end of each prayer service during the High Holidays. In many Sephardic machzorim, a supposed “name of God” is invoked—though not recited aloud—during this prayer (it is also found in the parnasah insert during the Amidah of many Sephardic weekday siddurim). That “name” is Dikarnosa (דיקרנוסא), which apparently comes from Malachi 3:10, though it is difficult to see how other than the appearance of the word די in the verse. Others link it to a fusion of Malachi 3:10 and the word nasah in Psalms 4:7, נסה עלינו אור פניך ה׳.

[Source](https://www.mayimachronim.com/is-kabbalah-kosher/)

*NOTE:* **It seems as if it's not a Malachs name, but rather one of G-Ds names.**

Answer (score 1):

I've always wondered about this supposed name of God. I have to believe that it is a mistake because it is most certainly a Spanish language derived name. It translates directly to "fleshy God", which could either refer to a goddess of lust or, more likely, the god who became flesh, ie, the Christian God.
I was told this by a local rabbi who speaks Spanish fluently, natively, and he thinks it shouldn't be in the machzor

Comment: http://moreshetsepharad.org/media/Anti-Maimonidean_Demons.pdf