# Holy names and mystic things added to Jewish prayer from Shabatay Tzvi sect

Tags: tefilla, names, mysticism-kabbalah

I read that the name "di-carnosa" (Fleshy God) and other names and prayer texts derive from Shabbatay Tzvi Sect influence in Sephardic Liturgy. I couldn't find a compiled and organised source for these add-ons.

In my experience I've found many such "paradoxal" additions and today I found that I was actually correct regarding the strange aspect of the prayers etc.

Does anybody actually have a list of all these texts etc? Better if in an academic format, I may write about it sometime in the future.

Comment: The origin of that particular Holy Name is the subject of a three-way machlochet (completely Kosher origin/taken from a Jew forced to convert to Catholicism/Shabbati Tsvi sect) and I suspect that any such list would also be full of similar ambiguities

Comment: Where did you read this please?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/113989/11486

Comment: Interesting comment on diaqarnosa in fn. 92 of Hakham Faur's essay [Anti-Maimonidean Demons](http://moreshetsepharad.org/media/Anti-Maimonidean_Demons.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

There is no consensus as to *who* added DiKarnosa, but most importantly is this error's deletion from our Mahzorim.

Some Sephardic liturgies, such as the Spanish-Portuguese and select Vienna editions of the Turkish rite delete it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question- and how do you know it's an error?